# Efficient way of sequentially detecting if certain strings occur at the beginning of other strings

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

Assume the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id   = c(1:8),
                 text = c("i like", "i like to", "oops", "i like to and", "i like it not", "victoria", "victoria secret", "victoria secret is"))
```

What I want to do is to:

- figure out if any given shorter string is part (more precisely) is the beginning of another string
- apply a minimum character length, e.g. the string has to have at least X chars (let's set it to 5 for the example)
- add the info to the data set which strings belong together.

My thinking is that I could sort my data frame based on the text response and the length of the text response and then check if the first string is part of any subsequent string, then I continue with the second string and check if it is part of the subsequent ones and so on. This is a computational nightmare, so I'm wondering if there's a computational more efficient way. I just thought that maybe first splitting up into words could make sense and then compare based on that? (comparing on full words would be fine, don't need to compare by every single character)

In addition, the problem could be that any longer response could be part of potentially all previous  responses, meaning that the information that needs to be stored could potentially require n-1 columns (or lists of that length).

Just to put it into perspective: my real-life data has ~100.000 rows.

Here's how I could envision a potential expected output:

```
  id                text group_1 group_2 group_3
1  1              i like       1       1       0
2  2           i like to       1       0       0
3  3                oops       0       0       0
4  4       i like to and       1       0       0
5  5       i like it not       0       1       0
6  6            victoria       0       0       1
7  7     victoria secret       0       0       1
8  8  victoria secret is       0       0       1
```

Note, I only need a column if a certain strings qualifies for at least two rows. So in this case I don#t want/need to add a group variable for the "oops" text.

- Texts 1, 2, 4 belong together because they all start with "i like" and they build up "sequentially", i.e. the second text is also part of the fourth text.
- Rows 1 and 5 also belong toegther because text 1 is part of text 5.
- Rows 6-8 also belong together for the same reason as texts 1, 2, 4 belong together (they build up on each other).

Alternatively, as a first step I could also work with an output that just gives me the information if a certain text is part of another text, so in the example just assign a 1 to all texts but "oops".

Comment: This kind of problem is solved efficiently using [prefix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) - there seem to be a few R implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Googling doesn't surface a lot on this matter. I found the triebeard package and will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize by doing string comparisons in C/C++. I've written an R function `match_start` in C that should get you most of the way there if you only have `1e+05` strings.

Given a character vector `x` and a positive integer `nchar_min`, `match_start` returns a list `l` of length `length(x)` such that `l[[i]]` is either `which(startWith(x, x[i]))` or `NULL`—the latter if and only if `x[i]` is `NA` or `nchar(x[i])` is less than `nchar_min`.

For efficiency, `match_start` assumes that the elements of `x` have a common encoding and that `x` is already sorted in ascending order. I would recommend:

- Forcing UTF-8 encoding of non-ASCII strings with `enc2utf8`.
- Ordering strings with `order(method = "radix")` so that you are always using the C collating sequence, for reproducibility.

You can see `?Encoding`, `?locales`, `?Comparison`, and `?sort` for details. (Everything is a bit scattered...)

```r
sig <- c(x = "character", nchar_min = "integer")
bod <- '
int N = INTEGER(nchar_min)[0];
if (N < 1) {
    error("\'nchar_min\' must be positive");
}

R_xlen_t n = XLENGTH(x);
SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, n));

/* Pointer to array of pointers to strings */
const char* *tx = (const char* *) R_alloc(n, sizeof(char *));
/* Pointer to array of string lengths */
int         *nx = (int         *) R_alloc(n, sizeof(int));
/* Pointer to array of indices of matching strings */
int         *ix = (int         *) R_alloc(n, sizeof(int));

/* One loop to initialize */
SEXP el;
for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    el = STRING_ELT(x, i);
    if (el == NA_STRING) {
        nx[i] = -1;
    } else {
        tx[i] = CHAR(el);
        nx[i] = (int) strlen(tx[i]);
    }
}

/* Another loop to compare strings */
for (R_xlen_t i = 0, m = 1; i < n; ++i, m = 1) {
    if (nx[i] < N) {
        continue;
    }
    ix[0] = (int) i + 1;
    for (R_xlen_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j, ++m) {
        if (nx[j] < nx[i] || memcmp(tx[i], tx[j], nx[i])) {
            break;
        }
        ix[m] = (int) j + 1;
    }
    el = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, m));
    memcpy(INTEGER(el), ix, m * sizeof(int));
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, i, el);
    UNPROTECT(1);
}
UNPROTECT(1);
return res;
'
match_start <- inline::cfunction(sig, bod, language = "C")
```

```r
df$text_utf8 <- enc2utf8(df$text)
o <- order(df$text_utf8, method = "radix")
l <- match_start(df$text_utf8[o], nchar_min = 5L)
df$id_match[o] <- lapply(l, function(i) if (!is.null(i)) df$id[o][i])
df
```

```
  id               text          text_utf8   id_match
1  1             i like             i like 1, 5, 2, 4
2  2          i like to          i like to       2, 4
3  3               oops               oops       NULL
4  4      i like to and      i like to and          4
5  5      i like it not      i like it not          5
6  6           victoria           victoria    6, 7, 8
7  7    victoria secret    victoria secret       7, 8
8  8 victoria secret is victoria secret is          8
```

`match_start` isn't *optimal* due to the inefficiency of storing all of the index vectors, when all you need is a recursive list or tree. I might be worried about tree depth, if you think think that complete nesting of your strings is a real possibility. (**Edit:** R supports tree depths up to `5e+05` via `options(expressions=)`, so recursion might be fine after all.)

Comment: Not entirely sure what non-UTF characters are, but I have a lot of „foreign“ characters, e.g. in Hindi. Using this prefix march method suggested in the comments to my original post destroys these. So handling these characters would indeed be benefitial.

Comment: So, the flagging of responses seems to work (just checked), Now I will need to compare the different approaches to figure out which one works best in my case. But thanks already for investing your time in helping me!

Comment: But it now throws an error that "make" is not found during compilation.

Comment: Kevin Ushey wrote a decent introduction to encodings [here](https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2018/02/21/string-encoding-and-r/). I found it helpful.

Comment: @deschen What does `Sys.which("make")` say? Is `make` in your `PATH`? If you are using Windows, then maybe you need to configure Rtools? See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html).

Comment: Confuguring rtools helped (had it installed, but didn't to this PATH thingy). Also thanks for the link to encodings. I remember this piece, I think I read it like 1-2 years ago, but tbh am not sure what to do about it, i.e. how I could convince R to print these unicode representations in their native form - but that's not an issue of your solution I guess (but the enc2utf8 part in your code doesn't do anything on my computer, i.e. it keeps the "Western" text as "unknown" and the Hindi responses as UTF8).

Comment: @deschen I think it is a Windows issue. You can try putting `LC_ALL=C` into a `.Renviron` and restarting R. Maybe see `?locales`.

Comment: @deschen I would say that `enc2utf8` is behaving as expected. `?Encoding` notes that ASCII strings are never marked with an encoding. The important thing is that strings using non-ASCII characters are marked as UTF-8.

Comment: If `enc2utf8` returns an identical character vector, then your strings were encoded correctly from the start, and there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts (have to be checked for runtime on a big data set).

- `gt5` are strings with the required length, should be straight forward.
- `occur` are strings that occur more than once. You can leave it out, but I thought it may also be nice to know. Might be expensive.
- `gr` is grouping by row number of occurrence of the largest common denominator. Only works if `text` is ordered by length of strings (either strictly, or, like in your case, by group-set). Uses `agrep` to do the fuzzy matching. (I have no idea how performant it is on large data sets). Also, you can replace `agrep` with `grep(substr(x,1,8),substr(text,1,8))` if you really only care about a 100% match of the first, say 8 characters of a string. (Definition of *beginning* of a sentence)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(gt5=nchar(text)>5, 
         occur=rowSums(sapply(unique(unlist(strsplit(text, " "))), function(x) 
           grepl(x,text)))>1, 
         gr=sapply(text, function(x) max(grep(substr(x,1,8),substr(text,1,8)))) )
  id               text   gt5 occur gr
1  1             i like  TRUE  TRUE  4
2  2          i like to  TRUE  TRUE  4
3  3               oops FALSE FALSE  3
4  4      i like to and  TRUE  TRUE  4
5  5      not i like is  TRUE  TRUE  5
6  6           victoria  TRUE  TRUE  8
7  7    victoria secret  TRUE  TRUE  8
8  8 victoria secret is  TRUE  TRUE  8
```

Note: Assigning 1 - 5 or 1 - 4 is a decision problem when only allowing one group. On the other hand, allowing more than one group may explode the number of total groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Need to digest it a bit, since I don't yet understand the logic of the assigned group, e.g. why in your case row 1 and 5 are grouped together and rows 2 and 4 (ideally it would group 1, 2, 4 together. But admittedly, 1 and 5 are also valid options and as you state in yout Note above, assigning several groups will grow complexity a lot.

Comment: @deschen Yep, this should just serve as a discussion starter. Feel free to take it apart at will :) Your definition of "beginning of sentence" might also be adjusted. So far the good part about this approach with grep is it only needs one scan through text. Btw, if you remove `max` from the `grep` you get all group relations.

Comment: I tried to deconstruct your code and think I understand it now. However, the approach will not only look at the text from the beginning. E.g. if I change the 5th value to "not i like is", it would still be flagged together with row 1.

Comment: @deschen In this case agrep should be replaced with `grep`. See edit.